# Regex : Get pattern which is between multiple patterns to be matched

Tags: python, regex

Say I have a string

```
versioned object base "/cm/common" (locked)
  created 2002-08-22T11:43:31+02:00 by Super-User (root.other@bb-soft-ccs)
  VOB family feature level: 4
  VOB storage host:pathname "atpccupd.cvc-global.net:/export/vobstore/obce/cm_common.vbs"
  VOB storage global pathname "/net/atpccupd.cvc-global.net/export/vobstore/obce/cm_common.vbs"
  database schema version: 80
  modification by remote privileged user: allowed
  atomic checkin: disabled
  VOB ownership:
    owner tmn/ccadm
    group tmn/HBGHS_CC_G
  Additional groups:
    group tmn/smc_cc
  ACLs enabled: No
  Attributes:
    FeatureLevel = 4
```

In the second line you see we have `created 2002-08-22T11:43:31+02:00 by Super-User (root.other@bb-soft-ccs)`.
I need to extract `Super-User` from here.

I need to write a regex such that first it matches created then the first date time like pattern then by and then get the string after that. The last string in the same line could either be a end or an email which needs to be pattern matched two.

So what I need basically is

r'created (matchdateTtime)by(matchtheuser)($orEmailMatchWithinBrackets)'

This is what I tried

```
import re
re.search(r'created (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}+\d{2}:\d{2})by(.*?)(emailmatchpattern|$)', text)
```

But this does not seem to be working.

Here is my email match pattern : `^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$`

Comment: try: ```re.search('(?<=by\s)(.*)(?=\s\(.*@)', text)```

Comment: there could be other things in place of date, so I need only those line which contains this date format in it

Comment: need to be preceded by both ```created``` and ```by``` ?

Comment: yes, and the pattern date

Comment: ok, date format is always like that ?

Comment: yes, date format is always like that

Comment: check my updated answer, let me know if ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
import re
re.search("(?<=created\s\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\+\d\d:\d\d\sby\s).*(?=\s\()", text)
```